# Assign new profile to user ABC when logged in as user ABC

Tags: profile, user-management, user-admin, user

When I edit any user from Manage Users, I am able to change the profile assigned to the user because I see a dropbox to choose the required profile from:

[image]

However, when on the edit page of the same user as I'm logged into SF (ex: logged into user Jane Doe and I'm editing the info of user Jane Doe), the same dropbox doesn't exist, only a link to the assigned profile, and therefore, I am unable to change the profile that is assigned:

[image]

Is there a way I can alter the profile in such a case. I'm guessing logging into ANOTHER user's account and then trying may work but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the profile of the user you are currently logged in as, nor can you change the current user's "active" status. This prevents an administrator from locking themselves out of the system. Another administrator may deactivate or change the user, however, even if it is the signed up user.

Example: John Doe signs up with salesforce.com. John eventually adds Jane Smith to the organization, and assigns her the System Administrator profile. Jane can now deactivate John or change his profile to a Standard User, and John can change Jane's profile or deactivate her user. However, neither can deactivate or change their own profile.

Comment: Good stuff. I looked around without much luck for materials online that speak to these signed up users and how they are potentially different from other users. Can you share any such links? need to read up on this.

Comment: There is no difference between the sign up user and any other user. You won't find any documentation on this, because no such documentation exists (if it did, there would be documentation stating that they are somehow special). There's a common theme with salesforce.com documentation: if it is not documented, it most likely does not exist. That's not to say there are no secrets, but their documentation publishers (the people that make the manuals) tend to avoid saying what the system can't, or doesn't do, and focus instead on what it can, or does, do.

Answer (score 0):

Logged-In/Context user can't change profile by itself. 
But you can give a try to the following approach:

- Create an email service and also create an inbound email handler.
- Create a VF to stimulate User edit page and on this page, show profile drop-down.
- When user clicks on save button after selecting desired profile send an email to above inbound email handler. In subject/body add
  userid and profile.
- Inside your inbound email handler write code to get userid and profile and change it.

Comment: This is interesting, Doga. You'd think the attempt to change own profile would be overridden/annulled by the system validation. Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and for me it works. Actually the context in which inbound email handler runs is of system admin. And a system admin can change the profile of other users.

Comment: True, but can the system admin profile of the CONTEXT user be changed with inbound email handler?

Comment: Nop, we need to have one system admin user fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the profile System Administrator on the user that you have registered your org with. You can create other Sys Admin users and change their profiles later, but not on the one you have signed up with.

If you could change it to a lower level hierarchy, then you wouldn't have a system admin user in your org, and due to security and the profile hierarchy, you can't set yourself from lower level to System Admin.

Comment: Require more clarification please. Let's say this signed up user is ABC. There is at least one other user XYZ in the same org who is also assigned the profile System Administrator. Now, how do I (user ABC) "change to a lower level hierarchy"? Also, "you can't set yourself from lower level to "System Admin"; did you mean the other way round 'cause you seemed to suggest earlier that user ABC can't move to lower level in the first place from System Admin.

Comment: You can't change your profile on the user that you've signed up with, because if you could do that, how would you go back to System Admin?

I'm pretty sure if you create another system admin user with the one that you've signed up with, then you should be able to change the profile on the newly created one.

Comment: Correct, I've done that last part that you mentioned - changed  a dozen users' system admin profile to custom profiles. But I want to have user XYZ as a system admin (so you have a system admin and that's taken care of), clone the profile system admin for user ABC (signed up one), and assign this cloned profile to ABC who will then have system admin privileges plus some customization. This simple requirement can't be done just because ABC happens to be the unfortunate signed up user? This doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The signed up user has a default system admin profile which can not be changed. It's like a power user that every other system has. Cloning the profile is the only way to go I believe.

Comment: Ok, even if I clone the profile and assign this clone to user XYZ so that she still has admin privileges, the system administrator profile is stuck like superglue to user ABC, no matter what? Would that be your conclusion?

Comment: You can't change your own profile because it would give you the ability to lock yourself out of the organization. It doesn't matter if there are other administrators, it's the principle of not allowing you to lock yourself out.

Comment: If XYZ logs in, they could change ABC, but ABC can't change their own profile because they would be locked out of their administrative privileges.

Comment: So is it about not able to change profile of OWN user or is it about not able to change profile of signed up (registered to org) user? If the former is true, then I would be able to change signed user ABC's admin profile logging into another admin XYZ's account, right?

Comment: It's both, you can't change profile of original user and also of yourself (the user that you're logged in as).

Comment: Got the major part; I'm trying to make sense of "If you could change it to a lower level hierarchy, then you wouldn't have a system admin user in your org". What about the other user XYZ who is an admin too?

Comment: Well if that was possible then the other system admin can change it too and then there wouldn't be any more system admins. Also as not being system admin, you won't have permissions to set yourself back to system admin... Makes sense?

Comment: Pretty much. But I'm still thinking if all system admins try to demote each other, wouldn't there ultimately still be one system admin user existing, because (1), once a user is demoted, he can no longer change a user's profile, and (2) he cannot change his own profile right.

Comment: That's the whole reason of the signed up user to be a power user...

Comment: e-bacho, can I modify your answer so newbies like me can relate to it better?

Comment: Sure, go for it..

Comment: There is no special protection for the "signed up user." Administrators leave organizations all the time; if there were no way to deactivate the user, this would be a security risk. It is true that the signed up user is more difficult to deactivate since they tend to be the "default user" for most tasks, but you can reassign those values and ultimately deactivate that user, but not from their own login.